# updating file based session with angularJS GET request

Tags: php, angularjs, session, laravel-5.1

I am having a really wield issue.

While sending a get request to save a session with angularJS

```
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/test-location'})
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
                // session was supposed to be saved
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('error getting session');
            });
```

My PHP: (Laravel v-5.1)

```
Session::put($key, $data);
Session::save();
print_r(Session::get($key));
die;
```

I am always getting the desired output to screen. however the session is not always being saved. ( sometimes is )

If i go in my browser to the page that the session is supposed to save at ( http://example.org/test-location ) it always saves the session and there is never any issue.

I always get COOKIE response from the ajax request.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: I think maybe the page need to refresh, or call the ajax call on new, to detect the session change.

Comment: @Meeh I checked the session files. It does not save.

Comment: I tried with a regular php session and it worked. so just a problem with laravels session